# Android Market - Want to see Best Applications

Tags: applications, google-play-store

Is there any way to see "Top Best (i.e. Top 10/50/100, etc.) applications" in Android Market as we are looking in AppStore ?

I means to say which applications/Games are famous amongst the people as "Angry Bird" is famous game in Appstore, applications may have either higher ratings or higher viewer, how do i come to know about applications in android market?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The web Market and the Honeycomb tablet Market app now have a whole set of pages listing the "Top X Apps" for a whole set of definitions of "Top". I can't see any way to get to all of these categories in the current Gingerbread phone version of the Market app, presumably they have less screen room to show all of these different views.

Here are some direct links to the web Market's pages, if you're on a tablet most of these should show up as links on the Market app's home page:

### Apps

- [Top Free Apps](https://market.android.com/details?id=apps_topselling_free)
- [Top Paid Apps](https://market.android.com/details?id=apps_topselling_paid)
- [Top Grossing Apps](https://market.android.com/details?id=apps_topgrossing) (see [this question regarding confusion over what defines "top grossing"](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/13146/top-grossing-apps-on-android-market))
- [Top New Free Apps](https://market.android.com/details?id=apps_topselling_new_free)
- [Top New Paid Apps](https://market.android.com/details?id=apps_topselling_new_paid)

### Games

- [Top Free Games](https://market.android.com/details?id=apps_topselling_free_game)
- [Top Paid Games](https://market.android.com/details?id=apps_topselling_paid_game)
- [Top Grossing Games](https://market.android.com/details?id=apps_topgrossing_game)
- [Top New Free Games](https://market.android.com/details?id=apps_topselling_new_free_game)
- [Top New Paid Games](https://market.android.com/details?id=apps_topselling_new_paid_game)

### Apps & Games Combined

- [Editors' Choice](https://market.android.com/details?id=apps_editors_choice)
- [Trending Apps](https://market.android.com/details?id=apps_movers_shakers)

To directly answer your question I would guess that most of the "famous" and "must-have" apps and games would show up in the "Trending" and "Editors' Choice" areas.

Answer (score 7):

Appbrain.com allows you to view the android market and which apps are most popular, most downloaded, hottest... all within different time frames.

Comment: thanx for the answer, i think this kind of rating, ranking facility should be on Android market , what you say!!

Comment: I agree, plus you should be able to browse the market from the cpmputer.

Answer (score 2):

If you go into the Market on your phone, then navigate down to a category (*e.g.*, games | Arcade & Action) there are three tabs: Top paid, Top free, Just in (*i.e.*, new)

I don't know what they use for their algorithm beyond the star ratings, nor if it varies from how things are presented on the official [Market](http://www.android.com/market/) website, but it does appear to be offering the top-rated/popular apps in each category.

Comment: @AI E. but overthere the applications which are listed at top, are also having 4.5 stars and below that the application has the 5 stars, same as you i am also knowing which algorithm they are using for listing the application in Top Paid, Top free and just in category.  Btw, thanx for the answer

Answer (score 0):

The answers above work, however I want to add another fact. All those results are limited based on your accounts "country setting".

If you want to see for instance, the **app overview for Germany**,
modify the URL like this:

https://play.google.com/store/apps?hl=de&gl=de

There you can still navigate, top, free, bestseller based on the country parameter

**Top Charts, Games, New Zealand:**

https://play.google.com/store/games?hl=en&gl=nz

where "hl" would be language in ISO language code ( works on all Google sites btw)
and "gl" is the country you want to load