# Top Grossing Apps on Android Market

Tags: google-play-store

I was surfing on Android Market and I found a list of [Top Grossing Apps](https://market.android.com/details?id=apps_topgrossing)? Do you know what does it mean specifically? Which is the criteria to appear in that lists?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> **Top Grossing:** applications and games generating the most revenue, including app purchases and in-app payments

From [Market Help Page](https://market.android.com/support/developer/bin/answer.py?&answer=1295940)

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a reference for you, except maybe the Wikipedia definition of [Gross profit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross_profit), but I assume it means the apps that have brought in the most money.

> [price] x [number of times downloaded] - [returns]

(Not an exact algorithm.)

Comment: Would assume the same, but bizarrely the top app showing at the moment is a free app? My Country https://market.android.com/details?id=com.gameinsight.mycountry&feature=apps_topgrossing In fact 6 of the top ten in that list are free apps?

Comment: Maybe the top grossing app right now wasn't always free?

Comment: Your parentheses lock wrong to me.

Comment: Or perhaps income from google ads counts too.

Comment: @CodeInChaos Eh, it was an attempt to be more accurate in identify variables with the brackets and parentheses. They're correct from a math standpoint... Order of ops would technically be sufficient. The actual algorithm would of course be more complicated, and the prices change all the time and it doesn't reflect that. And the point kind of works either way. You think I should edit to remove them just for readability?

Comment: I meant that it should be `[price] x ([number of times downloaded] - [returns])` else you're subtracting a number from a price. Or is `[returns]` something different from the number of returns?

Comment: @CodeInChaos: True. I simplified the calculation sample, since it's not really exact anyway.