# Does Google publish search trends for the Android market?

Tags: google-play-store

Does Google publish the searches on the Android market? Is there any way to see top searches or anything?

Comment: Not that I have found, no. All they seem to offer is the most popular apps/music/videos in a number of categories (Top Free, Top Paid, etc.)

Comment: For some of the categories that you can easily see (like trending) see the links in this answer: [Android Market - Want to see Best Applications](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/13740/156) but I think those are all for actual app installs, rather than searches.

Answer (score 2):

You can still get some trending information about android apps. For example  http://www.google.com/trends/?q=angry+birds

Comment: But isn't that search trends on the web, rather than in the Market, and it'll be every version of that app/term across all platforms instead of just Android?